# How to get checkbox value on button click in FormGroup

Tags: angular, formgroups

I have a list of checkboxes, the value of which will be dynamic as it will be coming from an api call.

The UI is as shown below:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

On click of the button, I want to get the values of the checkboxes.

I am trying to get the checkbox value on Submit button, but Iam not able to get the exact value.

Comment: Note you have used the wrong angular tag. [tag:angularjs] is for obsolete version 1.xx not more modern [tag:angular] for versions 2+

Comment: (change)="youtFunction($event)" on your checkbox.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this, `ngModel` binding being the one i'd use. But since you're already calling `(click)="updatefilter(servers)"` why not just adjust that function to keep track of which checkboxes are checked in a `this` variable

Comment: can you add the values for the form or the error; try this this.systemlogsform.controls['servers'].value